# nodejs selenium webdriverio webdriver.key(ENTER)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver-io

I have try hard to search this before asking the question without susscess. 
I only need to know how to send special characters (enter key, backspace etc) with nodejs (webdriverio) selenium.

With python I need to import selenium.keys and then do Keys.ENTER but I dont know how to proceed with javascript. My script is completed and working except for the need to press enter on some point of it and I am unable to find the way.

I have tryied with

```
driver.click("#X20").then(function(res){
            driver.keys(driver.Key.RETURN);
            driver.sendKeys(driver.Key.RETURN); ///and (just testing)


        })
```

None of it working :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

driver.keys('Enter');

is working :D thanks to all that take time reading my question